# Identifying registration ids from push notification servers

Tags: android, windows, push-notification, android-c2dm, mpns

I am setting up a server to send out Push Notifications to the various mobile platforms. Was wondering if it is possible to check the status of a push notification for Android's C2DM as well as for Windows Phone 7 MPNS? And also if it will retry to push if it fails?

How does the server identify the different platforms/device by? I know Apple has a 32 byte hexadecimal string in its token.

And lastly, what is the maximum message payload for Windows? There are 2 answers I heard and that it's unlimited or 1KB for header plus another 3KB for body. I'm confused.

1) Unlimited payload showing in this [link](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/chapter-8-introduction-to-windows-phone-7-notifications-for-iphone-developers)

2) And 1KB + 3KB over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Your reply is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Hend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out how to identify platform through the device token.

Anyway, using Manic Network to help in pushing the notifications. Great product.